# Android XML Error parsing: unbound prefix

Tags: android, xml

In this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:gravity="1" android:orientation="1" android:id="@id/blur_background" android:layout_width="-1" android:layout_height="-1" android:contentDescription="@string/recognize_image" layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:id="@id/medium_img" android:layout_width="@dimen/default_small_img_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/default_small_img_height" android:scaleType="7"
        layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="0" android:layout_width="@dimen/default_small_img_width" android:layout_height="-2"
        layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:textSize="18sp" android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" android:id="@id/recognition_stage" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="-2" android:layout_weight="1.0"
            layout_width="wrap_content"
            layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ProgressBar android:id="@id/recognition_progress" android:layout_width="24dp" android:layout_height="24dp"
            layout_width="wrap_content"
            layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View android:id="@id/recognition_divider" android:background="0x106000b" android:visibility="2" android:layout_width="@dimen/default_small_img_width" android:layout_height="1px"
        layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@id/frame_container" android:layout_width="@dimen/default_small_img_width" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="999.0"
        layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting the error at:

```
<ImageView android:id="@id/medium_img" android:layout_width="@dimen/default_small_img_width" android:layout_height="@dimen/default_small_img_height" android:scaleType="7"
    layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The error:

`Error:(3) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`

And in Android Studio Preview:

`Rendering Problems NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.`

Comment: `android:scaleType="7"` to `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: my android studio makes loads of complaints about this. No xmlns declaration, width and height not having android prefix, scaletype, orientation, visibility, gravity using numbers instead of value names. Add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the outermost `LinearLayout`

Comment: try adding this xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" in the root node.

Comment: @ColinGillespie I realize this is a post from a while ago, but I've inherited similar code to the above with things like `android:orientation="1"` but AndroidStudio is throwing errors like `Error:(4, 73) Integer types not allowed (at 'orientation' with value '1').` How can this type of code compile? It looks like its not throwing errors for OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/blur_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/recognize_image"
    android:gravity="1"
    android:orientation="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/medium_img"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_small_img_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_small_img_height"
        android:scaleType="7" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_small_img_width"
        android:layout_height="-2"
        android:orientation="0" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/recognition_stage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="-2"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@id/recognition_progress"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@id/recognition_divider"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_small_img_width"
        android:layout_height="1px"
        android:background="0x106000b"
        android:visibility="2" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_small_img_width"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="999.0" />

</LinearLayout>
```